# Where and how do typescript files become JS files in my project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm working on an MVC React project on Visual Studio.

Everything so far has been fine, but now I have a typescript file I've written myself, which I want to be able to use in the project. It's something of a learning process for me, so for now I just want to be able to use that Typescript in a generic HTML page (*not* React) via standard `<script src=...>` tags.

I understand it needs to be compiled to JS, but I don't know how to set that process up.

I've found and tried a lot of solutions involving webpack.config.ts, package.json, tsconfig.json, etc, but nothing ever works.

Is there a definitive and obvious way to do this? Or is there something specific about my project that I've got wrong?

If it helps, here's how the file layout looks in my project (webGL.ts is the one I'm wanting to deal with).

[image]

I've tried adding this to tsconfig.json:

```
"files": [
    "/ClientApp/webGL.ts"
 ]
```

My webpack.config.js file looks like this:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
const bundleOutputDir = './wwwroot/dist';

module.exports = (env) => {
    const isDevBuild = !(env && env.prod);
    return [{
        stats: { modules: false },
        entry: { 'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx' },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                { test: /\.tsx?$/, include: /ClientApp/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader?silent=true' },
                { test: /\.css$/, use: isDevBuild ? ['style-loader', 'css-loader'] : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use: 'css-loader?minimize' }) },
                { test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg)$/, use: 'url-loader?limit=25000' },
                {
                    //for reading font files
                    test: /\.(woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                    loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            new CheckerPlugin(),
            new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
                context: __dirname,
                manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
            })
        ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
            // Plugins that apply in development builds only
            new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                filename: '[file].map', // Remove this line if you prefer inline source maps
                moduleFilenameTemplate: path.relative(bundleOutputDir, '[resourcePath]') // Point sourcemap entries to the original file locations on disk
            })
        ] : [
            // Plugins that apply in production builds only
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
        ])
    }];
};
```

I suspect there's something I need to know or change in that file, but I'm a bit lost overall.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

**Update**:

I also tried manually creating a JS file of the same name, with which I would manually copy TS into it and adjust as needed (I'm not actually trying to learn TS here, I'm trying to learn webGL and three.js, and would just prefer to do it via TS if I can).

After making the JS file, it was automatically placed as a stub under the TS file, like so:

[image]

I feel like this has some amount of relevance, but I don't know how or why. The fact that they've been automatically joined tells me something. I still don't know how to get it working in the project though..!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Typescript to JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34816326/visual-studio-typescript-to-javascript)

Comment: @Abhinav Nope, not a duplicate of that one. Situation looks very similar but my project isn't automatically doing anything for me. I have a TS file, and I've made a JS file of the same name which automatically became a stub of the TS file (see update to my post). But I'm still facing the same issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Generally, you write typescript in your `src` directory, create a [`tsconfig.json`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file with your compiler settings, and then use [`tsc`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) to compile into javascript on another directory.

I have recently created a [basic typescript starter project](https://github.com/lucascaro/ts-node-starter) in github that you can check for reference.

In the `tsconfig.json` you can see that the code goes into the `src` directory, and the generated javascript goes into `dist`.

This repository uses `tsc` to compile via `npm run build`, but you can also use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/typescript/), especially if you are compiling a project with multiple files for web, or if you want to use other transpilers like babel, etc.

**example tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2018",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/node_modules/*"
  ]
}
```

#### In your project

In your specific use case, you are using webpack to transpile source files into javascript. Your `webpack.config.js` tells webpack how to do it. It is generating `main.js` in your `dist` directory (see `entries` in your config, and [documentation for entry points](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/entry-points/)).

**If what you want is to add a new file into the existing project** then you will need to add a new entry:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    main: './ClientApp/boot.tsx',
    webGL: './ClientApp/webGL.tsx'
  }
};
```

this tells webpack to build 2 separate files with all dependencies bundled in each of them, one for your `main` app, and one for your `webGL` file.

Comment: Thanks for this. Looks like I managed to solve it while you were editing your answer to add that last part. My solution is just as you said (in the last part), thanks.

Comment: Awesome, glad you could figure it out! Feel free to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), good job finding it!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution inside this seemingly unrelated tutorial: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Conversion-Guide

I needed to update the `entry` part of `webpack.config.js`, like so:

```
        entry: {
            'main': './ClientApp/boot.tsx',
            'webGL': './ClientApp/webGL.ts'
        },
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx']
        },
        output: {
            path: path.join(__dirname, bundleOutputDir),
            filename: '[name].js',
            publicPath: 'dist/'
        },
```

The name `webGL` is the name that will be given to the compiled TS file, which is then fed and processed according to the rules set out in the `output` section.

This can be referenced as required in HTML tags via:

`<script src="~/dist/webGL.js" ></script>`